# Creating dynamic charting tooltips

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, microsoft-chart-controls

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and WFC to create a point graph of data. To create my chart I have a datatable with 3 different columns; these are Date, Value and Serial. This table is generated dynamically off of an SQL query and then I plot the Date on the x axis and Value on the y axis. What I am trying to achieve is that when the mouse is over a point on the chart then a tool tip shows the Date, Value and the unique Serial relating to these values. At the moment I am using

```
myChart.Series["mySeries"].ToolTip = "XValue = #VALY \r\nDate = #VALX{d}";
```

however obviously this does not show the serial number against these values. I tried using a ToolTip event however had some problems when trying to convert from datapoint in pixels to an exact plot on the graph. I hope this question makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem, with thank to @vikas. Rather than try to assign a generic tool tip I have assigned an individual tool tip for each point.

```
        int points = 0;

        //For every row in the values table, plot the date against the variable value
        foreach (DataRow row in Values.Rows)
        {
            myChart.Series[Variable].Points.AddXY(Convert.ToDateTime(row["Date"].ToString()), row["Variable"].ToString());               
            myChart.Series[Variable].Points[points].ToolTip = Variable + " = #VALY \r\nDate = #VALX{d} \r\nSerial = " + row["Serial"].ToString();
            points += 1;
        }
```

So the counter starts at 0 then for every row in the datatable Values 1 is added to the number of points and a Unique ToolTip is assigned for each point individually.

Answer (score 0):

just for Idea

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                    StrSeries = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows(i)("Engage_Title"))
                    ChartRecentActivities.Series.Add(StrSeries)
                    ChartRecentActivities.Series(StrSeries).ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
                    ChartRecentActivities.Series(StrSeries).MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle
                    ChartRecentActivities.Series(StrSeries).MarkerSize = 7
                    ChartRecentActivities.Series(StrSeries).BorderWidth = 3
                    ChartRecentActivities.Series(StrSeries).ShadowOffset = 2
                    ChartRecentActivities.Series(StrSeries).Legend = "Default"
                    ChartRecentActivities.Series(StrSeries).LegendText = StrSeries
                    ChartRecentActivities.Series(StrSeries).LegendToolTip = StrSeries
                    ChartRecentActivities.Series(StrSeries).ToolTip = StrSeries

                    For j As Integer = 0 To ChartRecentActivities.ChartAreas(0).Axes(0).CustomLabels.Count - 1
                        dv.RowFilter = "Engage_Title = '" & StrSeries & "' AND Transaction_Date = '" & ChartRecentActivities.ChartAreas(0).Axes(0).CustomLabels(j).Text & "'"
                        If (dv.Count > 0) Then
                            dblPoint = Convert.ToDouble(dv.Item(0)(0))
                        Else
                            dblPoint = 0
                        End If
                        ChartRecentActivities.Series(StrSeries).Points.Add(dblPoint)
                        ChartRecentActivities.Series(StrSeries).Points(j).ToolTip = StrSeries & " = " & dblPoint.ToString()
                    Next
                Next
```

look at the last line

```
ChartRecentActivities.Series(StrSeries).Points(j).ToolTip = StrSeries & " = " & dblPoint.ToString()
```

Comment: Yes, it was only when hovering over point. So that the end user can see the Serial number of the product that has certain values. Thank-you.

Comment: I have attempted to convert your code from VB to C# (sorry if I didnt make the syntax clearer in the question) and dont seem to be able to get it to work properly. By the looks of this code it looks like there would be multiple series for each Serial number (correct me if I am wrong) and there is the potential for there to be hundreds of serial numbers. Thank-you very much for your reply though!

Comment: you are right, actually in your case you have only one series right, so you could remove inner for loop and chenge the logic or you please post the code, so I could modify

Comment: There isn't really any code to post. Simply a datatable with 3 column headers (Date, Value, Serial) and for every row within the data table I plot the Date against the Value. And then (using the code in the original question) I set the tool tip to show the Value and the Date. The only other code is that which defining the series name. Sorry I cannot be more help

Comment: I managed to get it working, however because I am a new member I am unable to answer my own question so as soon as my 8 hours are up I shall post the answer.